# Automate connecting to bluetooth devices from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, web-bluetooth

I've written a simple web app to factory-reset bluetooth devices that were accidentally turned on during shipping. The app scans for a class of bluetooth devices (those made by the company I work for), renders a list of devices found, and, when I click a button next to a device in the list, sends a reset message to the device.

This is a very manual process and I'd like to automate it. The problem is the Chrome dialog that asks for permissions to pair with a device. I am trying automate the app with Puppeteer, but I can't find a way to either (a) programmatically grant permissions to pair with a device or (b) to select the device in the dialog and click the "pair" button via Puppeteer. Anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible, or if there's a better way to achieve the goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Chrome.  (I work on chrome.)  The automation that does exist for Chrome's testing is layered such that actual Bluetooth connections aren't made.

Eventually we would like to enable this workflow via Enterprise configuration controls. But that is not started yet and there is no date commitment.

One alternative is to use node.js, though you lose the easy interface.  You might build the reset backend in a node server and have it serve a web page interface.

Comment: I have filed [issue 1040174](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1040174) to track the feature request for this type of automation via Enterprise policy and [issue 1040176](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1040176) for this type of automation through Puppeteer.